# How can I see more information about the failed test cases in the pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

```
import subprocess
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", range(19))
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", range(3))
def test_fw(x, y):   
     subprocess.call(['fw-test.exe', '--cal_tank', str(x), str(y)])
```

An example from output: I have some errors. How can I know how much they are?

```
.ERROR : Provided invalid 'mode' argument (17). Valid range from 0 to 16.
Usage:
--cal_tank mode rcv_index [output_csv_file]
.ERROR : Provided invalid 'mode' argument (18). Valid range from 0 to 16.
Usage:
--cal_tank mode rcv_index [output_csv_file]



========================== 57 passed in 7.78 seconds ==========================
```

Comment: As I see these errors are from fw-test.exe process which writes them on stderr/stdout, so you can grab stderr/stdout (read https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, you can use check_output() for example) and analize all errors by self, then to assert expected results

Comment: So how the code will be look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# To call:
#  python -m pytest ppp.py

import pytest
from subprocess import *

FWTEST_PATH = r'fw-test.exe' # Here should be full path to the fw-test.exe !

def call_fwtest(x, y, timeout=3):
    with Popen([FWTEST_PATH, '--cal_tank', str(x), str(y)],
            stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) as p:
        p.wait(timeout)
        return (p.returncode, p.stderr.read(), p.stdout.read())

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", range(19))
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", range(3))
def test_fw(x, y):
    returncode, out, err = call_fwtest(x, y)
    assert out == b'MY EXPECTED OUT'
```

You can set `timeout` argument to control the time after which you will get `TimeoutExpired` exception if the command `fw-test.exe` hungs up. To call it use command line `python3 -m pytest ppp.py` where "ppp.py" is supposed name of this file. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) about used functions of the "subprocess" module. Output is of type bytes, if you need, you can add `encoding` parameter to the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) call.

Comment: It is for Python 3 (I use 3.7), not for Python 2.x. It should print return codes and error message that option is invalid. Try to call it in this way: `LANG= python3 example.py` (space after '='). If you plan to use it with encoding different than ASCII, use encoding parameter on decode/encode the output. THIS IS ON LINUX. IF you use Windows, just call it without "LANG=". Also you can call your "fw-test.exe", also I strongly recommend you to use full paths always (`r"c:\my-folder\fw-test.exe"`)

Comment: 'LANG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: python3: can't open file 'pytest': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: LANG was for Linux only. Do you have pytest installed for Python 3 installation? Do you see it in `pip list` output?

Comment: Yes, I see it in the pip list.

Comment: It looks strange that Python tries to open pytest. What is the command line exactly? Are you sure that you use the python from the same installation as your pip? Can you import pytest from THIS python interpreter?

Comment: When I run this command "python3 ppp.py" nothing happened, when I run "python3 pytest ppp.py" I get  python3: can't open file 'pytest': [Errno 2] No such file or directory this messege.

Comment: Ah. You should not add pytest in your command line (python tries to open it as "pytest.py" which is missing sure). Call only `python3 ppp.py`. Also replace `["ls", "-666"]` with your command: `["fw-test.exe", "--cal_tank", str(x), str(y)]`. Wait a little, I will change the answer...

Comment: FWTEST_PATH = C:\Users\Gor\Desktop\MY_FOLDER\builds\FW\3.x\INTERNAL\SW\test_w32 r'fw-test.exe'    like this?

Comment: yes, but prefixed with "r" and in quotes like: `FWTEST_PATH = r'C:\Users\........'` -- so "r" is a prefix of all string

Comment: NameError: global name 'Popen' is not defined

Comment: `from subprocess import *` imports the name 'Popen'

Comment: AttributeError: __exit__